# An issue with a header in C++ [Solved. Missing ; after Range() function]

Tags: c++, data-structures, header

I ran into a problem with the header. I have a data structure assignment (LinkedList), and The header is already given int the assignment. I did all the other code, but when I ran the program, the error appeared regard the header! Here is the error:

[image]

**(The error is pointed to the "private")**

- Here is the header:

typedef int ElementType;

```
struct node {

    ElementType data;
    node * next;
};

class List {

public:
    List();                          //Create an empty list.
    bool Empty();                    //Return true if the list is empty, otherwise return false.
    void InsertAtEnd(ElementType x); //Insert a value x on the end of the list.
    void Delete(ElementType x);      //If value x is in the list, remove x.
    void Display();                  //Display the data values in the list in the order inserted.
    int Smallest();                  //Find and return the smallest value in the list.
    int Largest();                   //Find and return the largest value in the list.
    int Range()                      //Computer and return the range of the values in the list.

private:

    node * first;                    //Pointer to first node.
};
```

Comment: Well, yes, `;` before `private` is missing. More exactly, after `Range()`.

Comment: I'm struggling to deduce how this error message is in any way unclear. Did you at any stage of your debugging consider reading it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the line "`int Range()`" should be "`int Range();`". In other words, you are missing a semicolon on that line, which in the compiler's view, immediately precedes the "private:" keyword.

Answer (score 3):

`int Range()` doesn't have `;` after it.

Answer (score 3):

**It's exactly what it says.**

There's a missing '`;`' before '`private`'.

The last piece of code before `private:` should be a `;`, but isn't.

```
int Range() 
//         ^
```

Add it.

Comment: MAN! I don't why, but I have been reading the error as if it's (after "private"). It works now!

Comment: Since when the new name ;) ?

Comment: @vsoftco: About 1½ days so far

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error  in  your code sample above. The semi colon ; is missing for the

```
    int Range()
```

It should be

```
    int Range();

private:
...
```